# SharePoint 2010, Set Document To Read-Only after 48 Hours

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm a complete novice with SharePoint so I'm having difficulty framing the questions I have about the system for Google.

What I want to know is is it possible to make a document read-only after a time period (e.g 48 hours). Is this OOTB functionality or do I have to use c#?

Comment: This question might be better suited to http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Mhm, I forget this is a network of sites sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

This is one thought , check this !? ,  steps may works for you.
Create a designer work flow...

1 ) workflow should start on item creation only.

2 ) add an action: Pause for duration. Make the duration 2 days.

3 ) Add another action: Copy documents to another list with permission read only.